# object reference not set to an instance of object exception when I try to add element to an array of type List<string>

Tags: asp.net

In my project I've got a variable numtorust which represents the number of the toursits.
(for testing purposes numtourist = 2)

```
for (i=0,numtoursut; i++)
```

I create dynamically 5 checkboxes with assigned checkedChanged event for each of tourist. Also to keep track which checkbox to which tourist applies I add  attribute 'collection'

```
mycheckbox.InputAttributes.Add("collection", i.ToString());
```

In checkedchanged event handler - when a user selects a checkbox I  checked if its collection attribute is = 0 or 1 (first or second user). then I add checkbox value to `myche1` which is of type `List<string)` if collection attribute = 1.

But I when I decided to make one **array** of type `List<string>` with name  `Toursit` 
when I try to add an element to it I got an exception - Object reference not set **to an instance of object** in this row of my code

```
Toursist[Int32.Parse(chk.InputAttributes["collection"])].Add(chk.InputAttributes["value"].ToString());
```

Here is my full code

```
 protected void checkChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
     /*that doesn't work

     if (chk.Checked)
     {
         Toursist[Int32.Parse(chk.InputAttributes["collection"])].Add(chk.InputAttributes["value"].ToString());

         ((List<String>[])Session["chk"])[Int32.Parse(chk.InputAttributes["collection"])] = Toursist[Int32.Parse(chk.InputAttributes["collection"])];
     }*/

     //this works with myche1 of type list<string>
     if ((chk.Checked)&&(chk.InputAttributes["collection"].Equals("1")))
     {
         myche1.Add(chk.InputAttributes["value"].ToString());
         lblProba.Text += chk.InputAttributes["value"].ToString();
         Session["chk1"] = myche1;
     }
 }
```

edit 1:

teh new code of

protected void checkChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
List<string>[] Toursist = new List<string>[2];
//Session["chk"] = new List<string>[2]; 
for (int i = 0; i < Toursist.Length; i++)
{
    Toursist[i] = new List<string>();
   // ((List<String>[])Session["chk"])[i] = Toursist[i];
}

    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    if (chk.Checked)
    {

      if (((List<String>[])Session["chk"])[Int32.Parse(chk.InputAttributes["collection"])] == null)
        {
            ((List<String>[])Session["chk"])[Int32.Parse(chk.InputAttributes["collection"])] = Toursist[Int32.Parse(chk.InputAttributes["collection"])];


        }
            Toursist[Int32.Parse(chk.InputAttributes["collection"])].Add(chk.InputAttributes["value"].ToString());
            lblProba.Text += chk.InputAttributes["collection"].ToString();
            ((List<String>[])Session["chk"])[Int32.Parse(chk.InputAttributes["collection"])] = Toursist[Int32.Parse(chk.InputAttributes["collection"])];


    }
```

again the same mistake this time when I test if Sessio["chk"] == 0.

but If I uncomment (so I no more have this mistake)

```
// ((List<String>[])Session["chk"])[i] = Toursist[i];
```

on each postback event my session will be empty and I don't want!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't created any lists. When you create an array of lists, it won't automatically create all the lists in the array, you have to do that manually:

```
List<string>[] Toursist = new List<string>[numtoursut];
for (int i = 0; i < Toursist.Length; i++) {
  Toursist[i] = new List<string>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! But know I've got the same exception when I try to store Tourist[i] in a session like this  // ((List<String>[])Session["chk"])[Int32.Parse(chk.InputAttributes["collection"])] = Toursist[Int32.Parse(chk.InputAttributes["collection"])];

Comment: @MilkaSalkova: Have you assigned a `List<string>[]` instance to the session variable first?

Comment: no but why i should do this I just want to store Toursit[i]  in a ((List<String>[])Session["chk"])[i]. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @MilkaSalkova: You can't store anything in an array that doesn't exist yet. You have to put the array in the session variable before you can store anything in it.

Comment: hello I really appreciate your help. Thank you. I added soem code (edit1) but this way if I do what you tell me my session will be empty on each postback and finally in my session I will have only the last checked value

Comment: @MilkaSalkova: Before creating the array you should check if you don't have one in the session varaible (i.e. if the session variable returns `null`). If so, create the array, then after the loop that sets all the items, do `Session["chk"] = Toursist;`.

Comment: yes I did that already and now everything is fine! Thank you for your help again!!